# Programmatically add multiple breadcrumbs paths in Magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9

My products are in many categories like the following :

> Home-> Oral Care-> ToothPaste and Powders->Toothpastes
>
> Home -> Oral Care  Kids Oral Hygiene -> Toothpastes

I don't know this task how to implemented.

Can you please help me?

Comment: You can use directly : `Home > Toothpastes` ?

Comment: In programatically display  My products are in many categories like the following :Home-> Oral Care-> ToothPaste and Powders->Toothpastes  Home -> Oral Care Kids Oral Hygiene -> Toothpastes.But it will display only Home-> Oral Care-> ToothPaste and Powders->Toothpastes  but not display multiple breadcrumbs path

Comment: Home-> Oral Care-> ToothPaste and Powders->Toothpastes

Home -> Oral Care Kids Oral Hygiene -> Toothpastes

Comment: how to display programatically

Comment: I don't understand. You want display all breadcrumbs possible for `Toothpastes` category?